# Building Perl/C module using Microsoft VC (cl.exe) 2010 (10.0) Express and ActivePerl 5.12.4/32

Tags: windows, perl, visual-c++, mongodb, build

I'm facing this build problem using the configuration mentioned in the title. The Perl module I'm trying to build is `MongoDB::Connection`. I'm building via the CPAN shell, or manually like this:

```
C:\Opt\Perl512.32\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL
nmake
```

The command line for `cl.exe` is:

```
cl -c -I. -MD -Zi -DNDEBUG -DVERSION=\"0.43\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.43\" ^
  /Foxs/BSON.obj "-IC:\Opt\Perl512.32\lib\CORE" xs\BSON.c
```

Here are the error codes and their frequencies:

```
 6 C2040 'operator' : 'identifier1' differs in levels of indirection
                      from 'identifier2'
32 C2059 syntax error : 'token'
 7 C2081 'identifier' : name in formal parameter list illegal
54 C2143 syntax error : missing 'token1' before 'token2'
 2 C2371 'identifier' : redefinition; different basic types
```

It looks to me like all these errors are symptoms of a failure in the preprocessing stage.

I won't paste the entire output here, but the beginning is:

```
c:\opt\perl512.32\lib\core\win32.h(368) : error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ')' vor '*'
c:\opt\perl512.32\lib\core\win32.h(368) : error C2081: 'Stat_t': Name in der formalen Parameterliste ist ungültig
c:\opt\perl512.32\lib\core\win32.h(368) : error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt '{' vor '*'
c:\opt\perl512.32\lib\core\win32.h(368) : error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ')'
c:\opt\perl512.32\lib\core\win32.h(369) : error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ')' vor '*'
c:\opt\perl512.32\lib\core\win32.h(369) : error C2081: 'STRLEN': Name in der formalen Parameterliste ist ungültig
```

So given the clue `Stat_t`, I tried to track down the issue.

```
ack Stat_t c:\opt\perl512.32\lib\core\
```

So `Stat_t` is defined in `CORE\dosish.h` and `CORE\unixish.h`. Both are conditionally included from `CORE\perl.h`. Which is included from the file I'm trying to compile. So it *should* work.

- **What can I do to track the issue down?**
- **What's causing this failure?**

There are some similar errors floating about the net. Here a Google search for you:

http://www.google.com?q=perl+win32.h+c2059+c2143+c2081+c2371

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug report.
Maybe it's worth sending to CPAN bug tracker? https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=MongoDB

Comment: If it's a bug, then I don't think it is in the MongoDB module.